# how to drag and drop a button of specific sizes inside a layout in QTCreator?

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, qt-creator

I am a beginner in QTCreator c++. I have some basic questions.

1. I would like to drag and drop a button of 50x50 inside a layout. How to do that? As i've noticed the button is situated in the center of the layout ; when  want to drag it in right it goes again in the center.
2. After i'e put the pusg button, line edit and let's say a combo box do i need to define them in the .h file?
3. Do I need in .cpp to work with them and the main.cpp is used just for making all these buttons visible?
4. If I want a form that contains buttons, line edit, list view do i have to choose form: dialog? Is there a big difference between widgets, dialog and window when i speak about tools like: buttons, lists, tables ..and so on?
5. If I have an .a file that i need to use can i import it in QT and can I use it and print just specific results in Lists, Edit lines, combo boxes?

I've searched on the internet about QTCreator : drag and drop buttons examples but i didn't find a lot of stuff.

Comment: What kind of Layout you use? QHBoxLayout or?

Comment: I have the following options: Vertical  horizontal grid and form layout

Comment: Yes vertical is the QVBoxLayout and horizontal is QHBoxLayout.
Vertical is for rendering components one below onother, horizontal is for one next to other.
I think you need vertical layout. Select it and resize it to fit your needs, in order to test. Tell me if you add button inside, what will happen then?
Do you use ButtonBox, instead of Push button?

Comment: no I use push button. I resove the first question. I used layer in layer. Now I have a form that has 2 push buttons(print and clear) and a line edit. I would like to ask where o I have to initialize the buttons and the edit line in order to use connect to clear or print the text from the line edit?

Comment: You can connect them from there, as you can from programmatically.
The designer has its ui_myname.h where it contains the control initialization (setupUi) - you can see it from the generated cpp file, it is included there (Ctrl+Click over the include to follow).
This setupUi is setting the controls so you don't need, but if you have dynamic controls you will have to.

Comment: The dialogs are extended (improved) QWidget for exchange of info between user and application. For example dialog is executed with exec() and it has signals accepted() and rejected().
Where the standard buttons like save, ok, cancel, yes, no... etc. has a role. If the role is AcceptRole the dialog accept is triggered if it is reject the rejection is triggered by these signals.